# explanation of יַסְתִּירֵהוּ בְּסֵתֶר כְּנָפָיו לְעוֹלָמִים

Tags: tefilla, yizkor

The prayer "El Malei Rachamim" there is a passage

> לָכֵן בַּעַל הָרַחֲמִים יַסְתִּירֵהוּ בְּסֵתֶר כְּנָפָיו לְעוֹלָמִים

which by wikipedias [translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Malei_Rachamim) means

> Therefore, the Master of Mercy will protect him forever, from behind the hiding of his wings

What does this exactly mean?

From whom the deceased needs protection, and what does it mean to hide in the wings of the almighty?

The only guess i have is from [שבת פח עמוד ב](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%97_%D7%91) (Did not find translation in english)

> ואריב"ל בשעה שעלה משה למרום אמרו מלאכי השרת לפני הקב"ה רבש"ע מה לילוד אשה בינינו אמר להן לקבל תורה בא אמרו לפניו חמודה גנוזה שגנוזה לך תשע מאות ושבעים וארבעה דורות קודם שנברא העולם אתה מבקש ליתנה לבשר ודם (תהלים ח, ה) מה אנוש כי תזכרנו ובן אדם כי תפקדנו ה' אדונינו מה אדיר שמך בכל הארץ אשר תנה הודך על השמים אמר לו הקב"ה למשה החזיר להן תשובה אמר לפניו רבש"ע מתיירא אני שמא ישרפוני בהבל שבפיהם אמר לו אחוז בכסא כבודי וחזור להן תשובה שנאמר (איוב כו, ט) מאחז פני כסא פרשז עליו עננו ואמר ר'. נחום מלמד שפירש שדי מזיו שכינתו ועננו עליו ...

Here we find the term that someone hides in hashem, but what does this allegory exactly mean?

But still it is not understandable from whom the deceased has to get protection especially after he got his punishment for his sins.

Comment: Perhaps this is an allusion to the wings on the cherubim? Or it could be an allusion to G-d's general protection similar to the ideas that when G-d "introduces" himself to the Jewish people, he says, "I carried you upon the wings of eagles." It is metaphoric.

Comment: I got an answer from yeshiva.org.il: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/103830